# set difference and discard order

Tags: python, set

I have the following sets:

```
>>> s2 = set(((1,3),(2,3,6,4)))
>>> s1 = set(((1,3),(2,3,4,6)))
>>> s1.symmetric_difference(s2)
{(2, 3, 4, 6), (2, 3, 6, 4)}
```

I want to compare two above sets but set discards order of them, It means It return null set such as:

```
>>> s1.symmetric_difference(s2)
set()
```

**UPDATE:**

Indeed when sequence of two sets are difference, I want to sets supposes they are one set.
How can I define it with sets in python?

Comment: @JohnColeman oh no, empty means When I have two set and their value are same together but seqence of them is different. When sequence will be different, I want to set supposes they are same one set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your sets not as tuples but as sets. Since you need them hashable, use frozensets. Like `frozenset((1,3))` instead of `(1,3)`.

Btw you can also get the symmetric difference with `s1 ^ s2`.

Comment: Frozen sets are a good choice. I sometimes forget that such a collection is built into Python.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make order irrelevant is to make it the same. You could sort the tuples prior to putting them in a set:

```
>>> s2 = set(tuple(sorted(s)) for s in (((1,3),(2,3,6,4))))
>>> s1 = set(tuple(sorted(s)) for s in (((1,3),(2,3,4,6))))
>>> s1.symmetric_difference(s2)
set()
```

Comment: sort is very heavy, because I have more than 1 million record.

Comment: @PersianGulf sorting is a natural choice if you want the elements of the sets to be tuples. You never explained just what it is that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @PersianGulf More than a million tuples per set, or more than a million numbers per tuple?

Comment: I have to convert my tuple and dismiss tuple.